# System.IO.StreamWriter has no string constructor in .netcore 1.1

Tags: asp.net, constructor, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, streamwriter

I'm taking my first baby steps in .NET Core V1.1 under VS2017 community edition.

I ported some chunks of code to an ASP.NET Core project that utilizes System.IO.StreamWriter:

```
string fileName = "Hello_world.txt";

using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fileName))
{   
    // do stuff...
}
```

With this I get a compiler error:

```
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'
```

On the other hand the .NET API doc clearly states that a constructor with string is available, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netcore-1.1).

Can anybody tell me why there is no constructor that receives a string and where to find the correct API doc?

Comment: Looks like you created a .net core 1.0 project where this constructor was not available, as far as I remember. Would post this as an answer, however, it's a mere guess that would have to be first confirmed by yourself.

Comment: If you look at the Constructors section of the doc, you will notice there is no `string` constructor listed. Examples are the same for all frameworks, so they sometimes contain code that doesn't work in the selected framework.

Comment: I think my biggest problem was to find the correct API doc, thanks to Martin Ullrich I found the right one. Honestly, I find ASP.NET confusing because of all the different versions. At least for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StreamWriter` constructors taking string arguments will only be available in .NET Core 2.0 and higher. You can look up the availability at https://apisof.net/catalog/System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String)

In the meantime, you can create a `FileStream`, which is exactly [what the constructor taking a string does](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/4a213debad6635491d486ced984293d832e23068/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/src/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs#L139).

```
    string path = "foo.txt";
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.SequentialScan))
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, 1024, false))
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine("hey");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and especially the link. Did not find that resource before.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be fixed by using a **.NET Framework** project, rather than a **.NET Core** project.

All the 11 constructors should be made available in a .NET Framework project.

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

A `StreamWriter` object is actually a wrapper around a `Stream` object. You should create a `FileStream`, `MemoryStream`, or another kind of `Stream` and pass it to the `StreamWriter` constructor.

In .NET Framework, the constructor that takes a string, actually creates a `FileStream` under the hood.